# Open Sans Font issue with @font-face

Tags: css, html, frontend, font-face, typography

I am facing an issue with Open Sans @font-face. The character "a" and "e" seems to be messed. Please see the attached screenshot, It is showing in windows browsers only. Can anyone help me?

I know google font removes this error. But I need to include via @font-face

[Open Sans @font-face a and e seemed to be messed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D9GF.png)

Comment: Can you try to increase font-size and post the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Add Open Sans font from fonts.google.com.
add its link in html `head` tag.

**NOTE**: **Add font weight accordingly**

EXAMPLE:
in html `head` tag:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
```

in css

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
```

**delete Open sans font from your PC by going into control panel>fonts>open sans**

Comment: all available options in open sans font: <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i" rel="stylesheet">